# Getting exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser.parse(Z)Lorg/apache/fontbox/afm/FontMetrics;

Tags: java

I am getting exception while extracting pdf file of version 3.
Below are the jar files used in build path:

1.pdfbox-2.0.8.jar

2.fontbox-1.8.2.jar

3.commons-logging-1.1.2.jar

4.itextpdf-5.5.9.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser.parse(Z)Lorg/apache/fontbox/afm/FontMetrics;
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.Standard14Fonts.addAFM(Standard14Fonts.java:118)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.Standard14Fonts.addAFM(Standard14Fonts.java:97)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.Standard14Fonts.<clinit>(Standard14Fonts.java:50)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.<init>(PDFont.java:112)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.<init>(PDType0Font.java:120)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:83)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:143)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:60)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:838)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:495)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:469)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:150)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:139)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:391)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:227)
at com.citi.digitization.incoming.app.main.PdftoText.getText(PdftoText.java:30)
at com.citi.digitization.incoming.app.main.PdftoText.main(PdftoText.java:20)
```

Below is the source code:

```
String text = getText(new File(pdfPath));
System.out.println("Text in PDF: " + text);

static String getText(File pdfFile) throws IOException {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
        return new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
    }
```

Comment: Please format the errors properly (like code).

Comment: Check how many fontbox jars are on your classpath; seems like there is a version mismatch.

Comment: Indeed. The current version is 2.0.21. Use that for pdfbox and fontbox.